# Wait till previos process to end

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file

I am trying to simple thread login for Windows Powershell logic.

Code:

```
start call first_process
start call second_process
third_process
```

I am using start call to execute the first process and second process simultaneously and the third process needs to execute only after completion of the first and second process.

How is it possible in Windows Powershell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the `Start-Procces` cmdlet with the `-PassThru` parameter you can use a variable to check the current status, in this case you want the `HasExited` property. Below we'll check the status and then wait 15 seconds until both processes has exited.

```
$first_process = Start-Process 'first_process' -PassThru
$second_process = Start-Process 'second_process' -PassThru

while ($first_process.HasExited -eq $false -and $second_process.HasExited -eq $false)
{
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 15
}

Start-Process 'third_process'
```